# Documentation on question closure, please?

Tags: support

Question [How much does salary go up after probation period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64480/how-much-does-salary-go-up-after-probation-period) was closed.  Is there some documentation I missed that would show me how my question was not appropriate for the site, and even better, how to rework it?

Comment: Did you read the text in the close reason that said "for more information click [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694)" ?

Comment: My impression is that it is becoming more and more common to jack up the salary significantly after a probationary period.  I'm looking for general information about this trend.  I am not asking for information about this specific company.  That would be absurd, given its relatively small size, and given that I didn't even supply the name of the company!  Also note, my question has nothing to do with anything legal.

Comment: You can probably get the question reopened by changing the entire question to ask "How can you find out how much of a raise you will get after the probation period?"

Comment: Even if there is such a trend, how is that relevant to you? Whether you should start people off on a lower salary during their probationary period is a choice that your company's management will have to make, factoring in everything that they know about their location, attractiveness of the positions they have, the candidate pool, their culture and so on. Further, the title of your question doesn't match your edit and neither actually matches the real reason why you're asking. You need to make sure your question has a clear scope and focus.

Comment: @aparente001 You've misunderstood the reason. It's not that we're saying it's specific to your company, which as you say, you didn't identify so how could we know it. The reason is that it is a rule that is specific to each company. Starting a new employee with a low wage, and an automatic increase, for instance, is not a common practice or trend that I've ever heard of, and at least a few others haven't as well. So the close vote was because we cannot possibly know the reason behind the rule of those companies that DO do it. Heh heh, I said doodoo. :p

Answer (score 5):

You're asking people to answer a company specific question.  We can't do that.